# How to add a linked library for a cpp file in the CMakelists

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, this is a new user to use Cmakelists. I want to use a C++ file which can help me analysis the json file. Normally, when I make it executable, I run
g++ json.cpp -o -ljson
However, when I tried to add the c++ file in the ros package, I have some problems to make them.

Here is my original makefile:

```
 LIB=-L/usr/local/lib/libjson/ -ljson

haha: a.o
    g++ -o a -std=c++0x a.o $(LIB)
sdfds: a.cpp 
    g++ -c a.cpp
# dfasasdf:
#   rm  a.o a
clean: 
    rm edit a.o
```

Here is my CMakelist.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(rosauth)

```
## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp message_generation rostest)

#######################################
## Declare ROS messages and services ##
#######################################

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
add_service_files(
  FILES
  Authentication.srv
)

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
)

###################################################
## Declare things to be passed to other projects ##
###################################################

## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp message_runtime)

###########
## Build ##
###########

include_directories(
    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    

)
include_directories(
/opt/JSON/jsoncpp-src-0.5.0/libs/linux-gcc-4.8/
)

## Declare a cpp executable
add_executable(ros_mac_authentication src/ros_mac_authentication.cpp)

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
target_link_libraries(ros_mac_authentication
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES} crypto
)

add_dependencies(ros_mac_authentication ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencpp)


#############
## Install ##
#############

## Mark executables and/or libraries for installation
install(TARGETS ros_mac_authentication
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

#############
## Testing ##
#############

if(CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
  ## Add gtest based cpp test target and link libraries
  add_executable(ros_mac_authentication_test test/ros_mac_authentication_test.cpp)
  add_dependencies(ros_mac_authentication_test ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencpp)
  target_link_libraries(ros_mac_authentication_test ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${GTEST_LIBRARIES} crypto dl pthread)
  add_rostest(test/ros_mac_authentication.test)
endif()


add_executable(json
  src/json.cpp
)
add_dependencies(json ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(json
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES} json_linux-gcc-4.8_libmt
)
```

And I catkin_make it. it gives me this hint.

```
    Linking CXX executable /home/jimmy/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rosauth/json
    Scanning dependencies of target sick_tim310s01
    Scanning dependencies of target rbx2_utils_generate_messages
    Scanning dependencies of target sick_tim310
    Scanning dependencies of target sick_tim310_1130000m01
    Scanning dependencies of target sick_tim551_2050001
    Scanning dependencies of target sick_tim_datagram_test
    Scanning dependencies of target amcl
    [ 84%] Built target rbx2_utils_generate_messages
    Scanning dependencies of target robot_pose_ekf_gencpp
    [ 84%] Built target robot_pose_ekf_gencpp
    Scanning dependencies of target robot_pose_ekf_generate_messages
    [ 84%] Built target robot_pose_ekf_generate_messages
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 4 has invalid symbol index 11
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 5 has invalid symbol index 13
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 6 has invalid symbol index 13
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 7 has invalid symbol index 13
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 8 has invalid symbol index 12
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 9 has invalid symbol index 13
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 10 has invalid symbol index 13
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 11 has invalid symbol index 13
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 12 has invalid symbol index 13
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 13 has invalid symbol index 13
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 14 has invalid symbol index 13
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 15 has invalid symbol index 13
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 16 has invalid symbol index 13
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 17 has invalid symbol index 13
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 18 has invalid symbol index 13
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 19 has invalid symbol index 21
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_line): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 2
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o In function '_start':
    (.text+0x20)(undefined reference to 'main'.)
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[2]: *** [/home/jimmy/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rosauth/json] wrong 1
    make[1]: *** [rosauth/CMakeFiles/json.dir/all] wrong 2
    make[1]: *** unfinished tasks....
```

The json.cpp is linked to ljson.a in /usr/local/lib. I don't know how to solve this problem and tried for almost the whole day. Hope someone has known the reasons or solutions for this. Thanks!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267394/how-to-add-a-linked-library-for-a-cpp-file-in-the-cmakelists./) by [vcdanda](https://answers.ros.org/users/29640/vcdanda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2017-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try adding

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(JSONCPP jsoncpp)
```

and changing `include_directories` and `target_link_libraries` as

```
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${JSONCPP_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

and

```
target_link_libraries(json
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  ${JSONCPP_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Good luck.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2017-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vcdanda](https://answers.ros.org/users/29640/vcdanda/) on 2017-12-05**:
Thanks Akif. I've tried your method recently. It didn't work because it tells me an error:

```
undefined reference to 'json::Value::Value'
```

so the cpp cannot find the location of the json file.

I've tried other method like directly add jsoncpp below target_link_directories. It workd.

**Comment by [vcdanda](https://answers.ros.org/users/29640/vcdanda/) on 2017-12-05**:
But this jsoncpp is only a jsoncpp.a which is a static library. I want to add it in my path planner, it seems it cannot accept the static library there. You can see this question.
https://answers.ros.org/question/277265/cmakelists-compiling-questions/
but now I don't know how  add dynamic lib.